# Set integrated terminal default position

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default when opening the integrated terminal, it opens horizontally to the bottom of the editor.

How can I change the default position of the integrated terminal so that it is vertically aligned to the right of the editor, like when clicking the "Move to right" button?

[image]

**EDIT**:
Looking to set this in the settings.json

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try adding `"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right"` to your User/Workspace Settings

[image]

Comment: I also had to reload VS Code for this to take effect

Comment: Though [note](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67639#issuecomment-459349215): "_The setting is "defaultPosition" so it takes precedence only in a new window.
It stays there after reload since you probably changed panel position in your workspace and is written in lcoal storage which takes precedence.
I understand how this can be confusing, and we should fix._"

Answer (score 6):

In August 2021 using vscode 1.60.0 installed on Linux (Manjaro) from Snap, Select File>Preferences>Settings. Type 'terminal' in to the search and it is the first thing to appear 'Workbench>Panel>Default Location'. This contains a drop-down with left, right and bottom as options.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image that show how to position the terminal in Visual Studio Code]

You can see the image it's easy.
And if you close the Visual Studio it open by default in the position that was.

Comment: when I open a new window, it doesn't open in the position that is was

Comment: Be sure to save all when you finish.